Ontario trailer towing weight rules — Class G; Silverado 3500
I want to determine how much weight can be legally towed in Ontario with a 2011 Silverado 3500 using a class G license.
Use case: Determine if there is a way to legally tow a backhoe without getting an AZ transport truck license. The backhoe hasn't been purchased yet, so the weight is unknown.
What needs to be considered when assessing if a towing weight setup is legal?

Class G license towing weight rules. (I'm having difficulty finding an Ontario.ca website that clearly outlines the rules.)
Towing weight limit of the truck. (It should be listed in the owner's manual.)
Weight limit of the trailer.
Other?


Frame challenge - consider using a combination of Bobcat and Ditch Witch, both fairly light, to replace the backhoe. Not sure why "Allowed to drive any car, van or small truck or combination of vehicle and towed vehicle up to 11,000 kilograms, provided the towed vehicle is not over 4,600 kilograms." is particularly unclear.

@JonCuster I guess I'm just having a brain fart. "Allowed to drive any car, van or small truck or combination of vehicle and towed vehicle up to 11,000 kilograms, provided the towed vehicle is not over 4,600 kilograms. A pickup truck towing a house trailer exceeds 4,600 kilograms but the total combined weight of the truck and trailer does not exceed 11,000 kilograms is deemed a Class G."  https://www.ontario.ca/document/official-ministry-transportation-mto-bus-handbook/licence-classes-and-combinations ... To me, the first sentence seems to contradict the second sentence.

@JonCuster Why do they say "provided the towed vehicle is not over 4,600 kilograms"? The house trailer example seems to suggest the towed vehicle weight is irrelevant if the total combined weight of the truck and trailer does not exceed 11,000 kg.

That appears, to me, to be a specific exemption allowing a pickup truck to tow a 'house trailer' aka 'mobile home' to the site it will be placed. As long as truck+trailer is under 11,000kg in that specific case it is still legal. You are towing a backhoe or other construction equipment, so are limited to 4600kg. Should you tow a mobile home to place on your site, the total of truck+trailer can be 11,000kg.

@JonCuster Thanks. Regarding, "consider using a combination of Bobcat and Ditch Witch, both fairly light, to replace the backhoe." The use case is: Small scale mining/prospecting. 1) Remove ~1ft of soil to expose bedrock; 2) break the rock using expanding grout, Nxburst, or possibly a hammer attachment; 3) move the rock; 4) drive to various rough terrain locations on the site, including driving on bedrock. It's actually a friend of mine doing the work, not me. His best guess is a backhoe is the best tool for the job. A backhoe was used previously at this site by the former mining claim owner

Fair enough, go with what you've got (or can get cheap).  There are hammer attachments for the small Bobcats, and they can do all the rest, perhaps not as fast as a large backhoe. This sounds more like prospecting for fun, but that is only my impression.

@JonCuster You have to read the exact laws, but I suspect it's an RV exemption, not a trailer home. Many states have similar RV exemptions with similarly obscure terms.
